# Isn't the Force always with you?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

Characters frequently say, "may the force be with you." Based on what we learn about midi-chlorians, isn't the force always with you?

These organisms exist in one's body, and they are responsible for one being force sensitive and able to use the force.

They are usually in the same quantity/proportion at all times, I would assume.

Why do characters use this phrase if it doesn't really make sense?

Comment: Short answer; **Yes.** "*The Force will be with you. Always.*"

Comment: People use a lot of phrases that don't make a whole lot of sense considered logically. (A lot of greetings and valedictions are in this category.)

Comment: “With you” can also mean “on your side”, or “working in your favour”, as opposed to just “near you”. Maybe that’ the meaning behind the phrase.

Comment: Saying "God be with you" doesn't really assume that he is actively working against you at any time.  I'd guess the Star Wars quote is similar, since it was stolen from that.

Comment: It quite often gets misplaced on high shelves, along with car keys, in my household.

Answer (score 7):

Yes - technically, the Force is a part of all living things, and would therefore always be with someone *per se*. It cannot be given or taken, at least not with a simple phrase.

Rather, the phrase is a take on a traditional parting such as "God be with you." or "Vaya con Dios" (Spanish for 'Go with God'). Neither of those phrases make much sense, either, considering that most versions of the Christian faith teach that God is *always* watching over us. But people say it anyway, as a gesture - a way of wishing the departee a safe journey and good luck.

Equivalent phrases might be "Good journey" (I'm looking at you, Masters of the Universe) or "Good luck" - anything that says to the other person "I wish you well while we're apart".